# Pimoroni Speaker Phat i2c and using the pins

Tags: gpio, i2c, hat

Is it possible to use the pins on top of a raspberry pi hat that uses i2c? I am trying to use the Pimoroni Speaker Phat and control a motor using GPIO at the same time.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This tells you the exact pins that the Pimoroni Speaker Phat uses. As far as I remember I just used the pins that weren't being used by the speaker phat and it worked out ok. https://pinout.xyz/pinout/speaker_phat#